# "strip" onnx graph from its constants (initializers)

Tags: onnx

I have an onnx graph/model that has big constants in it, so it is taking a lot of time to load it and parse it. Can I "strip" the data from the graph, so I inspect the graph nodes without its data ?

Answer (score 1):

Initializer is one of the field in GraphProto. You should be able to clear initializer field with simple python script. I haven't tested the following code but should be something like this:

```
import onnx

def clear_initializer(model_path):
    model = onnx.load_model(model_path)
    model.graph.ClearField('initializer')
    onnx.save_model(model)
```

references:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class
[https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/2e7099ee7c37b196c197c9a084a97698a41da232/onnx/**init**.py](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/2e7099ee7c37b196c197c9a084a97698a41da232/onnx/__init__.py)